# What's in between "single" and "double"?

Tags: single-word-requests, portmanteau-words

I'm trying to think of a word that basically communicates something in between a single and a double.

Is there such a thing as half of a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)?

How would you communicate something that is in between a single and a double?

Comment: How on earth do you tie half a knot?

Comment: You're not, but you kinda are... If you tied two ropes together with a double overhand, you're essentially left with a knot with four loops. A single overhand would be two loops. The knot I'm tying has three loops... I'm tying a single with one strand, then a double with the other, but in "knot math" that does not add up to a triple, it's one single less that a double... but not a single... I need help.

Comment: A singled double?

Comment: Half singling a double?

Comment: Three half-tuples?

Comment: Are you looking for "a square knot"?

Comment: @Centaurus, No. If you're a knot nerd, the square not is ABOK #1402, what I'm tying is a variation of ABOK #1410.

Comment: @tchrist, this isn't a duplicate, that question is about [Ordinal Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), this one is about [Tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

Comment: @ShemSeger I meant to flag it as possible duplicate, not slam it down.  I keep forgetting that I have superpowers. Sorry! I'm not sure what's best now. I can reopen it, and will if there are other votes to do so.

Comment: Isn't it just half? [Half hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/halfhitch/), [half knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/halfknot/index.php?Categ=basics), [half windsor](http://www.animatedknots.com/tiehalfwindsor/), etc. I remember a lot of knots having half versions from my macrame days...

Comment: @VampDuc No it's not. It's a flat overhand that's been separated into one single and one double but still tied into a single flat knot.

Comment: @ShemSeger I'm having a hard time visualizing such a knot. I'd describe it (based on what I said before) as an overhand-and-a-half, but since you say that is wrong (and I defer to you, I'm not an expert), I have no idea.

Comment: Half again as much.

Comment: You'd think that there is a term for that in the parlance of knot-tying, much like there is a "half-double" crochet stitch.

Comment: Give us a photo or diagram.

Comment: Forget about the knot, focus on the tuples. Is there a word for half a tuple?

Answer (score 4):

There is a Latinate prefix, *sesqui-*, for 'one and a half', which is occasionally used for terms like *sesquicentenary*. How you adapt this to your very specific situation (and whether it will mean anything to anyone else when you do so) is up to you.

Comment: I was able to discover that Sesquidupal was a word which means two and a half, but I can't find a series of tuple and a half words.

Comment: @ShemSeger: I think the word for one and a half would be "sesquuple"

Comment: Wikipedia indicates that various Latin roots are used with the "uple" endings. Unfortunately, there seems to be no Greek equivalent to "sesqui-": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix

Answer (score 0):

I'd say half-double. Refer to crochet terms.

Comment: How is a half double not a single?

Comment: Because it's only half doubled haha.  One half double is half the increase a double would be, so 50% more

Answer (score 0):

Half of double is single. If you're talking about a quantity rather than groups of integral units, you can say "one and a half."